# how to get objects which param contains substring in value using JSONata?

Tags: jsonata

here is data:

```
[
  {name:"Hello"},
  {name:"World"},
  {name:"Hello World"}
]
```

how to build proper JSONata query to get all entries where `name` contains `World`?

I did try the `"'World' in name"`, but it returns `undefined`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$contains()](http://docs.jsonata.org/string-functions.html#containsstr-pattern) function within a filter expression (`$[...]` filters the input array):

```
$[$contains(name, "World")]
```

See this in the JSONata Exerciser: http://try.jsonata.org/BJDPGXzEG